# What are the criteria used by the Government Pension Fund of Norway to add a company to its excluded company list?

Tags: economy, ethics, norway

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_Pension_Fund_of_Norway) provides some general information related to the exclusion of companies on ethical grounds:

> (..) holds portfolios of real estate and fixed-income investments.
>   **Many companies are excluded by the fund on ethical ground**s.

This is confirmed by [the Council of Ethics web page](https://etikkradet.no/excluded-companies/) and [the actual list](https://www.nbim.no/en/the-fund/responsible-investment/exclusion-of-companies/) is provided by Norges Bank Investment Management.

I am wondering if the criteria (at least in part) is public information and a company is aware of why it has been included in the list.

**Question:** What are the criteria used by the Government Pension Fund of Norway to add a company to its excluded company list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to all be available on the websites you've linked to in your question.

The [Council's Activities](https://etikkradet.no/councils-activities/) page from the Council on Ethics website lists a number of criteria under which a company may be excluded:

> - serious or systematic human rights violations, such as murder, torture, deprivation of liberty, forced labour, the worst forms of
>     child labour;
> - serious violations of the rights of individuals in situations of war or conflict;
> - severe environmental damage
> - acts or omissions that on an aggregate company level lead to unacceptable greenhouse gas emissions
> - gross corruption
> - other particularly serious violations of fundamental ethical norms.

The list of excluded companies you have linked to includes a column indicating the criterion for exclusion.